# Fragment to fragment communication, not working properly for some reason

Tags: android, object, nullpointerexception, fragment, communication

I am trying to communicate between two fragments by passing an object from one fragment to another.  In GradeListFragment, I have a listView, and in GradeInfoFragment, details are displayed depending on which selection is made on the listView.  I display messages to the Log to make sure I can reach the required methods and to make sure I can retrieve the information between fragments, which I can do but I still get NullPointerException for some reason when I try to call the method that will handle the data in my GradeInfoFragment

**GradeListActivity.java**

```
package bcs421.jorgeramirez.hwk.gradeapp.presentation;

import bcs421.jorgeramirez.hwk.gradeapp.businesslogic.GradeData;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;


public class GradeListActivity extends FragmentActivity implements SendGrades {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gradelist);


    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.frag_container1, new GradeListFragment());


    int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();

    if((rotation == Surface.ROTATION_90) || (rotation == Surface.ROTATION_270))
    {
        ft.add(R.id.frag_container2, new GradeInfoFragment());

    }

    ft.commit();


}

@Override
public void sendGradeInfo(GradeData thisGrade) {
    Log.d("Hello!", "In sendGradeInfo function!");
    Log.d("HEy!", "This category is: " + thisGrade.getCategory());
    GradeInfoFragment f2 = (GradeInfoFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frag_container2);
    f2.getData(thisGrade);
}






}
```

**GradeListFragment.java**

```
package bcs421.jorgeramirez.hwk.gradeapp.presentation;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log; 
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import bcs421.jorgeramirez.hwk.gradeapp.businesslogic.GradeCollection;
import bcs421.jorgeramirez.hwk.gradeapp.businesslogic.GradeData;


public class GradeListFragment extends Fragment implements Serializable, SendGrades {



SendGrades SG;
public GradeCollection collectedGrades;

@Override
public View onCreateView(   LayoutInflater inflater,
            ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gradelist, container, false);
ListView lv = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listViewGrades);

ArrayList<String> namesArrayList;
ArrayAdapter<String> namesArrayAdapter;


Activity a = getActivity();
Intent i = a.getIntent();

namesArrayList = i.getExtras().getStringArrayList("grade_list");
collectedGrades = (GradeCollection) i.getSerializableExtra("grade_collection");
namesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(a, R.layout.item_gradelist, namesArrayList);
lv.setAdapter(namesArrayAdapter);
lv.setClickable(false);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            GradeData thisGrade = collectedGrades.GetItem(position);
            Log.d("Hell!", "This category is: " + thisGrade.getCategory());
            SG.sendGradeInfo(thisGrade);


    }
    });


return v;
}




@Override
public void onAttach (Activity activity)
{
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try
    {
        SG = (SendGrades)activity;
    }
    catch (ClassCastException e)
    {
        throw new ClassCastException("You need to implement the sendGradeInfo method");
    }
}




@Override
public void sendGradeInfo(GradeData thisGrade) {

    GradeInfoFragment f2 = (GradeInfoFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frag_container2);
    f2.getData(thisGrade);
}
}
```

**GradeInfoFragment.java**

```
package bcs421.jorgeramirez.hwk.gradeapp.presentation;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import bcs421.jorgeramirez.hwk.gradeapp.businesslogic.GradeData;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class GradeInfoFragment extends Fragment {

EditText categoryText, numberText, gradeText, descText;

@Override
public View onCreateView(   LayoutInflater inflater,
            ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gradeinfo, container, false);


categoryText = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.editCat);
numberText = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.editNumber);
gradeText = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.editGrade);
descText = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.editDesc);

return v;
}

public void getData(GradeData receivedGrade)
{
    double gd = receivedGrade.getGrade();
    String gValue = Double.toString(gd);
    Log.d("Hello!", "Filling in grade information!");
    categoryText.setText(receivedGrade.getCategory());
    numberText.setText(receivedGrade.getNumber());
    gradeText.setText(gValue);
    descText.setText(receivedGrade.getDescription());
}

}
```

**LogCat**

```
04-06 13:26:28.161: D/Hell!(2229): This category is: Lab
04-06 13:26:28.161: D/Hello!(2229): In sendGradeInfo function!
04-06 13:26:28.161: D/HEy!(2229): This category is: Lab
04-06 13:26:28.161: D/AndroidRuntime(2229): Shutting down VM
04-06 13:26:28.161: W/dalvikvm(2229): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1d44b20)
04-06 13:26:28.161: E/AndroidRuntime(2229): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-06 13:26:28.161: E/AndroidRuntime(2229): Process: bcs421.jorgeramirez.hwk.gradeapp.presentation, PID: 2229
04-06 13:26:28.161: E/AndroidRuntime(2229): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-06 13:26:28.161: E/AndroidRuntime(2229):     at bcs421.jorgeramirez.hwk.gradeapp.presentation.GradeListActivity.sendGradeInfo(GradeListActivity.java:45)
04-06 13:26:28.161: E/AndroidRuntime(2229):     at bcs421.jorgeramirez.hwk.gradeapp.presentation.GradeListFragment$1.onItemClick(GradeListFragment.java:55)
04-06 13:26:28.161: E/AndroidRuntime(2229):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
04-06 13:26:28.161: E/AndroidRuntime(2229):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1113)
04-06 13:26:28.161: E/AndroidRuntime(2229):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2904)
04-06 13:26:28.161: E/AndroidRuntime(2229):     at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3638)
04-06 13:26:28.161: E/AndroidRuntime(2229):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
04-06 13:26:28.161: E/AndroidRuntime(2229):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-06 13:26:28.161: E/AndroidRuntime(2229):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-06 13:26:28.161: E/AndroidRuntime(2229):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-06 13:26:28.161: E/AndroidRuntime(2229):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-06 13:26:28.161: E/AndroidRuntime(2229):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-06 13:26:28.161: E/AndroidRuntime(2229):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
04-06 13:26:28.161: E/AndroidRuntime(2229):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-06 13:26:28.161: E/AndroidRuntime(2229):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: please check for f2 instance in sendGradeInfo method... it should not be null

Comment: Try debugging you application. Is f2 the null parameter?

Comment: Hey guys! I ran an if statement that would send a message to the Logcat if f2 is null, and f2 is indeed null. I have no idea why!

Answer (score 0):

try to set all fragments as support `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`

And instead `getFragmentManager()` use `getSupportFragmentManager()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this , 
In this line ,

```
GradeInfoFragment f2 = (GradeInfoFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frag_container2);
```

You are trying to get the fragment using "R.id.frag_container2" , but this is not the id/tag of the fragment. Its the container id. So it return null.

In order to get the fragment by tag, you have to set the tag to the fragment when you adding it.

Try ,

```
ft.add(R.id.frag_container2, new GradeInfoFragment(), "your_tag_name");
```